# The meaning of '' short of quitting"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

Can anyone please tell me what " short of quitting" mean in the following sentence:
The characteristics of bad managers run the gamut from micro managing, to bullying, to just plain ineffective. And, short of quitting, there isn't much you can do since it is unlikely that your boss is going to change.

And I'd also like to know if it is a fixed expression, what I mean is that can I use it in another example?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we wish to describe the options available in some situation, we can use the fixed expression "short of [some action]" to state that an ultimate (and usually undesirable) action is excluded. We stop short of some final step.

My neighbour's dog barks all night. Short of shooting the animal dead, I do not know what I can do.

My attempt at building a shed without plans has resulted in a lopsided and unstable structure. Short of knocking it down and starting again, there are not many options available to me.

My boss shouts at me every day, and makes me perform menial tasks. Short of resigning, I don't know what I can do.